# How to prevent duplicate value in multiple excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I already made a macro that can prevnt du^plicate value in one excel sheet now I couldn't activate it il all workbook see below code

```
Option Explicit
Public Flag As Boolean


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Flag Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("f")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Application.CountIf(Range("f:f"), Target) > 1 Then
            Flag = True
                MsgBox ("Ce PO existe déjà !")
                Target.ClearContents
            Flag = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the [`Workbook_SheetChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event

Comment: when I type it it asking for new name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment one could modify PEH's code like that

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns("F")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        Dim wks As Worksheet, sumCountIf As Long
        For Each wks In Worksheets
            sumCountIf = Application.CountIf(wks.Range("F:F"), Target) + sumCountIf
        Next wks

            If sumCountIf > 1 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS 'in any case of error re-enable events

                MsgBox ("Ce PO existe déjà !")
                Target.ClearContents
            End If

    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS: 'ensure that you never end up with EnableEvents off.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Based on PEH's recommendation a neater version might look like that

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns("F")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        On Error GoTo EH          'in any case of error re-enable events
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim wks As Worksheet, sumCountIf As Long

        For Each wks In Worksheets

            sumCountIf = Application.CountIf(wks.Range("F:F"), Target) + sumCountIf

            If sumCountIf > 1 Then
                MsgBox ("Ce PO existe déjà !")
                Target.ClearContents
                Exit For
            End If

        Next wks


    End If

EH: 'ensure that you never end up with EnableEvents off.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You could improve it by putting the `If sumCountIf > 1` into the `wks` loop and `Exit For` on `>1` so it doesn't need to run all 20 worksheets and cancels if it found in worksheet 2 already.

Comment: Thank u so Much  its works exactly like  what I want ... So Im confised I click accept on this answer or the one  before

Comment: At least you should upvote both answers and as PEH gave the right idea and also added the version you wanted it's okay to accept his answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Workbook.SheetChange event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) as suggested in BigBen's comment.

Note that the `SheetChange` event **needs to be in `ThisWorkbook`** and not in the code of a `Worksheet` and you need to specify the sheet for your ranges like `Sh.Columns("F")` and `Sh.Range("F:F")`

Also Note that instead of the `Flag = True/False` you can do `Application.EnableEvents = True/False` to prevent re-triggering the same event with `Target.ClearContents` which should be the standard approach. `If Flag Then Exit Sub` can be removed too then.
Adding some error handling is a good idea, so you never end up with `EnableEvents` turned off.

```
' (ThisWorkbook scope)

Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns("F")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Application.CountIf(Sh.Range("F:F"), Target) > 1 Then

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            On Error Goto ENABLE_EVENTS 'in any case of error re-enable events

            MsgBox ("Ce PO existe déjà !")
            Target.ClearContents
        End If
    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS: 'ensure that you never end up with EnableEvents off.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats works but he look just in one sheet for same value .... I want him to check all sheets (f:f) if that value exist

Comment: @SidiMed Well that is something different then. You would need to loop through all sheets and check `Target` against all sheets. Give it a try and if you get stuck or errors ask a new question.

Comment: I tried that using for each ws but that didnt work as axpected

Comment: @SidiMed we can help yo to improve/fix your code, but therefore you need to show it in a question.

Comment: I just added this before  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns("F")) Is Nothing Then
For Each Target In Sh

Comment: @PEH: Did you test the last version? I think you need to keep track of the sum of CountIf, or am I wrong?

Comment: @PEH: But what happens if ValueA is on Sheet1 once and on Sheet2 also once. I think the OP would like to have  ValueA only once on Sheet1 and Sheet2 in total.

Comment: @Storax Shi… you are right. Sorry. Mine was for `>0` :( to less coffee. Removed it, since you added it to your anwser already. I removed my comment as well.

Comment: @Storax See Storax's answer for checking *all* workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your code directly in the sheet, put your code in the WorkBook and use the "Workbook_SheetChange" event :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Obj As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

This way, the code will be applied to all sheets of your WorkBook.

Comment: Please add some description in your answer.